# Flutter Installation Issue

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, mobile, development-environment

I have macOS sierra 64 bit, and I am trying to install flutter SDK kit.
When updating my path to export `PATH=$PATH/Users/mayankvaswani2008/Developer/flutter/bin` and using the command

```
echo $PATH
```

I get this path

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin/Users/mayankvaswani2008/Developer/flutter/bin
```

then when I type flutter doctor or flutter by itself, it says that

```
-bash: flutter: command not found
```

Please help

Comment: `/sbin/Users/mayankvaswani2008/Developer/flutter/bin` - that part is wrong i assume? change `PATH=$PATH/Users/....` to `PATH=$PATH:/Users...`

Comment: That works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) said,

You need to add in a colon between paths in MacOS. You'll want to go in and remove the flutter path, then run this: `PATH=$PATH:/Users/mayankvaswani2008/Developer/flutter/bin`

Should do the trick.

Comment: @MayankVaswani Mark it as answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Terminal: Go to Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal. This will launch the Terminal application.

2.Locate the Flutter SDK: Assuming you have already downloaded the Flutter SDK, find the directory where you extracted the SDK files.

3.Set the PATH environment variable: In Terminal, type the following command to open your shell profile file (e.g., .bash_profile, .zshrc, or .bashrc):

**nano ~/.bash_profile**

4.Add the Flutter SDK path: Within the opened file, add the following line at the end:
**export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/flutter/bin"**

5.Save and exit the file: Press Ctrl+X to exit the nano editor, then press Y to confirm the changes and Enter to save the file.

6.Apply the changes: In Terminal, run the following command to apply the changes made to the shell profile:

**source ~/.bash_profile**

7.Verify the installation: Run the following command to verify if the Flutter SDK is set up correctly:

**flutter doctor**